# python string parse numbers in a more robust way

Tags: python

Got a string after scraping a website.

```
 '<p class="NewsItemContent" style="font-size: 18px;">;As of March 18, 1999, 
6 p.m. Pacific Daylight Time, there are a total of 70;events and 16;planned  
in this area. This total does not include adjacent cities.</p>'
```

How could I parse out 70, 16.
Just want a more robust way. Wording might change a little bit, but always a total of {};events and {};planned.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Split the string on spaces.  For each result in the split list, if it contains exactly one semicolon, and all the characters prior to the semicolon are digits, you found your number.

Comment: Use regular expressions

Comment: Tried split on ";", but think  that might not be a very robust way. If I could "a total of 70" then "and 16;planned"  to further split, I think that might be more robust.  How could you extract a sub string "a total of 70" from a string.

Answer (score 1):

Not a very clean solution but here we go:

```
import re

s = ('<p class="NewsItemContent" style="font-size: 18px;">;As of March 18, 1999, '
     '6 p.m. Pacific Daylight Time, there are a total of 70;events and 16;planned  '
     'in this area. This total does not include adjacent cities.</p>')

s = s.split('a total of ')[1]  # split by 'a total of' to get the second part

print(re.findall('\d+', s)[:2])  # finding the first two digits
```

```
['70', '16']
```